# Migrating From SVN To Git - Duplicate Tags with "@"?

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn, tortoisegit

I'm attempting a one-way migration from SVN to Git.  While all's well with most of my repos, every once in awhile I end up with "duplicate" refs for a given SVN tag, and I'm not sure why.

As an example, here's a snapshot of an SVN repo's /tags directory, shown with TortoiseSVN's Repo Browser.  Notice tag "657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar":

[image: SVN repo]

Upon migrating to Git, if I view the contents of .git/packed-refs, the *vast* majority of tags come out as expected - one entry each.  Oddly, this "657" tag (and one other) yields multiple entries, some followed with an @-number:

```
07d524b93e8fc6957d06f687f83db0ba897890a9 refs/remotes/tags/657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar
ee48ab8efa3f4ed5f54d0d1a3dd8fac76205ab9e refs/remotes/tags/657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar@327
23eccb461e341a2f7bd0af03159c61600c888e7c refs/remotes/tags/657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar@657
```

In order to convert my remote SVN tags/branches to real Git tags/branches in the migrated repo, I use the following commands (from [this](http://blog.zobie.com/2008/12/migrating-from-svn-to-git/) handy tutorial):

```
git branch -r | sed -rne 's, *tags/([^@]+)$,\1,p' | while read tag; do echo "git tag $tag 'tags/${tag}^'; git branch -r -d tags/$tag"; done | sh
git branch -r | grep -v tags | sed -rne 's, *([^@]+)$,\1,p' | while read branch; do echo "git branch $branch $branch"; done | sh
```

After running the commands, I push my migrated Git repo to a bare repo & clone it again (to remove the SVN references).  If I then view its revision graph with TortoiseGit, everything is as expected...except for that weird 657 tag (and one more) off to the side:

[image: Git Revision Graph]

So the question is: what's causing just those two tags (out of dozens) to be migrated in that way - where they end up with multiple references in Git - while 99% of tags come out just fine?  What's the proper way to avoid it (to achieve a 'consistent' revision graph)?  Notice that the tag/branch conversion commands explicitly look for "@" in the names; clearly the article's author knows that this may happen...yet I can't figure out why.

**~Addendum~**

Looking at my source SVN repo's revision graph, the 657 tag is not shown:

[image: SVN Revision Graph]

If I view the commit log starting at the 657 tag, it only goes back a handful of commits (vs starting at any other tag shows history back to the beginning of time, as expected).  So it looks like something is screwy with the source SVN repo - though again, I have no idea why/what - or why this yields multiple 657's in Git?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that you have 3 different SHA1 codes for each tag which are as follows:
**07d524b93e8fc6957d06f687f83db0ba897890a9** refs/remotes/tags/657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar
**ee48ab8efa3f4ed5f54d0d1a3dd8fac76205ab9e** refs/remotes/tags/657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar@327
**23eccb461e341a2f7bd0af03159c61600c888e7c** refs/remotes/tags/657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar@657

Use the following to get the details of what the SHA1 is for:(You will probably find the answer)

git cat-file -p 23eccb461e341a2f7bd0af03159c61600c888e7c

or

git cat-file -p ee48ab8efa3f4ed5f54d0d1a3dd8fac76205ab9e

Comment: ee48ab8efa3f4ed5f54d0d1a3dd8fac76205ab9e yields the commit corresponding to SVN #327 (as I'd expect - it's listed as refs/remotes/tags/657_RemoveTravellogProgressbar@327), etc.  I'm still not sure how I can use this to determine why it's actually happening (for just those 2 tags), though...